# Approximating sines and cosines using up to five terms of the Taylor series

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, homework, numerical-methods

I have one programming question:

> The sine and cosine of \$x\$ can be computed as follows:
>
> > \$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} - \dots\$
> >
> > \$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - \dots\$
>
> Your task is to compute the sine and cosine for given values of \$x\$ (where \$x\$ is in radians) using the above series up to 5 terms.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> First line will contain \$N\$, the number of test cases. Next \$N\$ lines will contain the input values of \$x\$:
>
> > \$1 \le N \le 50\$
> >
> > \$0 \lt x \lt 10\$
>
> Each value of \$x\$ can contain up to 2 places of decimal in radians.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> 2 \$N\$ lines, corresponding to the \$N\$ input values of \$x\$.  For each input, you will output 2 lines. First line will be the sine and the second line will be the cosine of \$x\$.  An error margin of \$\pm\$0.001 will be tolerated while evaluating the answers.  Please round off your answer to 3 decimal places.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 5
> 2.83
> 3.24
> 0.99
> 2.74
> 5.04
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output *[sic]*
>
> ```
>  0.309
> -0.943
> -0.089
> -0.963
>  0.836
>  0.549
>  0.392
> -0.914
>  0.195
>  2.746
> ```

and what I have tried:

```
public class Trigonometric_Ratios
{  
  int factorial(int number)
  {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
      result = result * i;
    }
    return result;
  }

  void calc(double x)
  {
    double sinx=0,cosx=0;

    int i,j = 0;

    int c;
    for(i=1;i<10;i+=2)
    {
      c=i;
      sinx += Math.pow(-1,j++)*Math.pow(x,i) / factorial(i);
      if(i>0)
      cosx+=Math.pow(-1,j)*Math.pow(x,c-1)/factorial(c-1);
    }
    sinx=Math.round( sinx * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0;

    cosx=-cosx;
    cosx=Math.round( cosx * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0;
    System.out.println(sinx+" \n"+(cosx));
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int n;
    Trigonometric_Ratios tr=new Trigonometric_Ratios();

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    n=sc.nextInt();

    double a[]=new double[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      a[i]=sc.nextDouble();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      tr.calc(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Please review my code.  In particular, I am concerned about performance, and would appreciate suggestions on reducing the time complexity.

Comment: What a lot of languages, looks a lot like Java to me. Where is the class Trigonometric_Ratios? Does this compile? How do the results look? Homework? I wouldn't worry too much about compile time just yet.

Comment: You can avoid calculating `Math.pow(x,i)`. You need all powers of x 1..9. This can be done simply by multiplying the previous power of x with x. You also need `factorial` for all values 1..9 so do calculate `fractorial(n)` by `fractorial(n-1)*n`.

Comment: `i` is always `>0` so you can remove the condition `if(i>0)` from your loop.

Comment: @JohnMark13 yes i correct class name and output is same like question i post here

Comment: @MrSmith42 when i am using `factorial(n-1)*n` it is giving Exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: @MrSmith42 how can i get previous power of x

Comment: @Rahul Kulhari: I meant: store the value of the previous loop run and use it in the next loop run.

Comment: well `cos(x)` is `root under(1-sin^2(x))`. So you can only evaluate the value of `sin(x)` and get `cos(x) = Math.sqrt(1-(sin(x) * sin(x)))`.

Comment: @tintinmj: I doubt that this is faster than calculating `cos(x)`  because computing `sqrt` is slow because its implementation is also based on a series calculation. But only profiling can show if it is faster. It is worth a try.

Comment: The simplest way to reduce time complexity would be to use an array to store the factorial of all values upto 10(which is the max factorial that you are calculating). Doing it once will be much better than calculating the factorial many times which you are currently doing. Also you are calculating power of x 2 times. It would be better to calculate `x^(c -1)` and then multiply it with x to get `x^c`. Also the variable `c` is unneeded. It is `i` at every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of computing `Math.pow()` from scratch, multiply the previous numerator by *x*<sup>2</sup>.  (I suspect that `Math.pow()` uses logarithms so that it can handle the general case.)  Also, instead of computing the factorial from scratch, multiply the previous denominator by the next two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
cos(X) = sum (Cn) where Cn=x^2n/2n!

sin(X) = sum (Sn) where Sn=x^(2+1)n/(2n+1)!
```

So, `Sn=Cn*x/(2n+1)`

```
Cn=S(n-1)*x/2n
```

Start from `C0=1` and compute `S0=C0*x, C1=S0*x/2, S1=C1*x/3` etc.

Comment: `Start … compute … etc` saving the space to store not only `x*x`, but `n!` or its inverse, too, for 1 < n < 10. How do the accuracies of `r / 5040`, `r / 3 / 8 / 5 / 6 / 7` and `r * (1/5040)` compare?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question calls for a precision of ±0.001, it should be safe to stop iterating as soon as a term has an absolute value of less than 0.0005.